# Drupal Forms API #States

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, drupal-forms, islandora

## Background

I have a form created using the [Islandora XML Form builder module](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/ISLANDORA113/Chapter+10+-+Enabling+Form+Creation+with+the+XML+Forms+Modules#Chapter10-EnablingFormCreationwiththeXMLFormsModules-IslandoraXMLFormBuilder).  This form dynamically adds fields using AHAH.  For a given fields set, the first fieldset will have a name like foo[0], the second foo[1], etc.  Within this fieldset can be additional fields.  So the bar field on the first would be named foo[0]bar, the bar field on the second is foo[1]bar, etc.  If the bar field is itself a fieldset then the baz field on the 1st instance of the bar set in the second foo would be foo[1]bar[0]baz.

## Question

I need to modify this form to use the Drupal form states so that the visibility of foo[x]bar[y]baz is based on the value of foo[x]bar[y]qux.  If I were writing pure jQuery, I could set the state based on `$this().prev(":input[name$=qux]")`.  Can I use this type of reference for the Drupal Forms States or can I only use absolute selectors?

Comment: I ended up creating a module to do most of this work:  https://github.com/Michigan-State-University/islandora_xml_form_builder_states.  As is common with Islandora, it is on git instead of being on the drupal site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only absolute selectors work for the drupal states system.